# Why do window.location and window.location.href return a Page Not Found Error in MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application that sends users to a shopping cart page to view the summary of their items prior to checkout. When the user clicks the checkout link, it triggers this JavaScript function:

```
function CartCheckOut() {
    var cartitems = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CartItems))';
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           datatype: "application/json",
           data: { cartitems: cartitems },
           url: '@Url.Action("CheckOut", "ShoppingCart")',
           success: function (result) {
             if (result) {
               window.location = result;
             }
           }
    });
 }
```

Which in turn sends them to the Shopping Cart Controller that processes the request and returns a URL with a merchant key so they can be redirected to the merchants site to complete the checkout process.

To simplify the description of the problem, I am excluding other pieces of the Checkout method but it simply returns a string URL with a key/pair value. But the resulting problem is the same irrelevant of the URL that is returned to the function as it always results in a Page not found error after landing me on the same page that launched the call.

```
public string CheckOut(string cartitems) 
{
    return "http://www.google.com";
}
```

If I use window.open(result); within the CartCheckOut function, a new page is launched and I'm taken to the URL that gets passed back from the controller.

But if I use either

```
window.location = result;
```

or

```
window.location.href = result;
```

I get a Page not found error with no redirection to the specified URL.
I've also tried assigning the Controller method as an ActionResult and RedirectResult to perform a return Redirect(url) but the results are the same.

Is this method of performing a redirect incorrect or could I be missing some critical piece?

Comment: i guess your ajax is skipping javascript code. What i mean is that result is always empty. Can you just put a alert(result) statement before "window.location = result;"?

Comment: can you show what is the actuall code you put instead of example of google.com

Comment: i mean show your ``CheckOut`` action

Comment: I actually debugged the result to check the value of the result when receiving the error and it does contain the url prior to the crash. But to your point, I had already tried your suggestion as well and the result does contain the url. Also, remember that window.open does work without any other code changes to affirm the url is present.

Comment: Ehsan, I am not currently at my system to provide the full CheckOut Action Code but the actual url does contain some sensitive information used to authorize the payment process so I would not be able to post the actual url. But the problem persists using any URL and I would expect a different behavior. I used the google.com uri as an example since I'd think that url is as simple as it can get. Is there any reason that you suspect that the url is the problem?

Comment: @Mark: If you can't post the URL here, then you should never be sending a user directly there. They will be able to see all of this "sensitive information" right in their navigation bar.

Comment: Point taken. You're right. The sensitive information is actually in the code block, not the url. Anyway, another piece of information is that the url that is posted in the address bar on the page after failure to redirect is localhost:62509/ShoppingCart/Action?Length=10